# Jquery select val . Не проверяет на моб версии

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
jQuery(document).ajaxComplete(function (e) { //срабатывает после успешного AJAX
    var formClass = $('#wpcf7-f5-o1 form').attr('class'); //Wordpress Contact Form 7

    if (formClass.split(' ')[1] === 'invalid') { // Если какое-то поле не валидно, то форме добавит класс invalid

        //Получаю val у селекта
        var hearFromVal = $('#hearFrom').val()
        if(!hearFromVal) {
            $('#hearFrom').css('border-color', '#ff0000');
        } else {
            $('#hearFrom').css('border-color', '#bbb');
        }
   }
});
```

Данный код работает на декстопе. На моб не срабатывает. Не могу понять, почему. Другие проверки (на почту, телефон, длину поля) срабатывают везде правильно.

Answer (score 1):

**UPD**

Ещё дело может быть в проверке `if(!hearFromVal)`, потому что пустая строка, например, вернёт `true`, и проверка пройдена не будет.

```js
let args = [null, 0, false, ' ', undefined];

for(let i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
    if(!args[i]) {
    console.log(i+' '+false);
  }
  else {
    console.log(i+' '+true);
  }
}
```

Но без воспроизводимого примера, просто по куску скрипта сказать трудно.

---

Возможно, дело в конструкции `formClass.split(' ')[1]` - Вы проверяете строго второй элемент массива. А, может быть, в мобильной версии класс `invalid` идёт другим по счёту (добавляются ещё какие-то классы, например).

Если уж Вы делаете такую проверку на наличие класса, то нужно по всему массиву пройтись, а не брать какой-то определённый элемент.

Comment: Он работает правильно, т.к. внутри `if (formClass.split(' ')[1] === 'invalid') {` находятся все остальные условия (на почту, тел и т.д.) и они срабатывают

Comment: @РомаХр, так а что не срабатывает тогда?